# How to add items to Multiple interface in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have a below 2 Interface I am trying to add items but getting error **undefined** at **this.request**

```
export interface Details {
   ItemID:string;
   name:string;
   Quantity :any;
}
export interface Request{
    detail :Details [];
    userId:number;
  }

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
 
 request: Request=[];

saverData(){
    this.request.detail.push({ItemID:"test", name:"ch",Quantity:5.8});  //error request undefined
    this.request.userId=9;
   console.log( JSON.stringify(this.request));
}
```

** My Output should be expected as follows:**

{
"request": [
{
"ItemID": "string",
"name": "string",
"quantity": 0
}
],
"userId": 0
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `type` of `request` object. it should be type of `BOMRequest` but you are using `Request[]` type.

this

```
 request: Request=[];
```

should be,

```
request: BOMRequest = []; // empty array will not work. You have to define all properties here with their default value.
```

---

**OR**

---

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
 
saverData(){
    const request: BOMRequest = {
      detail.push({ItemID:"test", name:"ch",Quantity:5.8}),
      userId: 9 
    }
    
     console.log( JSON.stringify(this.request));
}
```

Comment: just add partial request: Parital<BOMRequest> = []; with that it is possible to have empty arrray it will make an optional to all fields